# how to convert human date to unix by strotime

Tags: php, unix

Can anyone help , i want to to make simple script as anyone insert human date like `2013 - 9 - 25 19:10:00 P.M`   to milliseconds Unix .

is it possible using `strtotime`.

I want anyone to show me how to make the whole human date (2013 - 9 - 25 19:10:00 P.M ) be in one variable so i can convert it then echo it

Comment: thats what `strtotime` does, i recommend to read how to use it from PHP's documentation

Comment: `$str = '2013-9-25 19:10:00 P.M'; echo strtotime($str);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strtotime` or `timestamp`

`timestamp` example

```
$dt = new DateTime("Fri Dec 18 2013 14:25:00 GMT-0600 (MST)");
$ts = $dt->getTimestamp();
```

`Strtotime` example

```
$ts = strtotime("Fri Dec 09 2013 14:25:00 GMT-0600 (MST)");
echo date("r", $ts);
```

In your case:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2013-9-25 19:10:00 P.M');
```

Comment: ok could you show me how to simply make the the date variable with html  input methods :)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @sskoko i`m trying to make simple script for everyone who insert the human date to be converted to unix date in miliseconds , so i want to know how to make the input html form and gather them all to a one variable so as to convert it :)

Comment: Read again JTC answer. Where is the problem?

Comment: @sskoko No prob i want simply an example of html input form to make anyone input the date he want :)

Comment: @SamehKhaled that simply does not match your question. You want me to show you a html form, parse it with php and output the timestamp? So, you want us to make all work for you? just do some [google](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: @JTC no i`m not asking for this i simply have a complex script which i want to simplify ok tnx for help